# How to autoimport types at TypeScript Nuxt.js app?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I want to use my custom types at Nuxt.js app and want them to autoimport for every component I making. I edited tsconfig.js with `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.vue", "**/*.tsx"]` and put my types to `types/index.d.ts`:

```
export interface IUser {
name: string
address: string
}
```

But when I compiling app it says `Cannot find name 'IUser'` at `let users: IUser[] = []`
I just don't want to import type `IUser` to every component. How can I make Nuxt.js import type definition everywhere itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare global.

```
// types/index.d.ts
declare global {
  interface IUser {
    name: string
    address: string
  }
}

export {};
```

```
// components/whatever.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{ user: IUser }>();
</script>
```